# $http not passing on .success

Tags: angularjs, http, express

I have a function that uses textract (https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract).

```
$scope.textract = function(fileURL) {
        var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/textract',
        params: {
            fileURL: fileURL
        }
    };

    $http(req)
        .success(function(status, data) {
            console.log('status is: ' + status);
            console.log('data is: ' + data);
        })
        .error(function(status, response) {
            console.log('error status is: ' + status);
            console.log('error response is' + response);
        });
};
```

On an express server, I have:

```
function countWords(text) {
    var s = text ? text.split(/\s+/) : 0; // it splits the text on space/tab/enter
    return s ? s.length : '';
}

app.get('/textract', function(req, res, next) {

    filePath = path + req.query.fileURL;

    textract(filePath, function(error, text) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log(text);
            return res.status(200).send(countWords(text));
        } else {
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        };
    });

});
```

On the server, `console.log(text)` and `countWords(text`) work.

Question: On the client, `$http` prints on `.error`, in other words, it's not passing on `.success` (which is I believe what it should do, because on the server the word counter is working ok).

Any ideas?

Comment: Since it is printing .error it should say "error status is"... what does it say?

Comment: `error status is:`
`error response is25`

(25 is the number of words that the server calculated when doing `res.status(200).send(countWords(text));`

Comment: Your wrapper/library should be smarter than that. The error should be quite ugly can you paste the whole error message please

Comment: This is all I got: http://cl.ly/image/2t1a310G3R34

Comment: send json response and double check headers

Comment: I believe there's an error on res.status. Not sure what. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehn4cvn4/